# Which types of collisions contribute to electrical resistivity?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, electrical-engineering

Do electrons **only** bump with other electrons in a circuit and that only causes resistance? Or do they bump with the nucleus as well?

[Here's a post](https://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/circuits/Lesson-2/Electric-Current) I have been studying recently:

> The path of a typical electron through a wire could be described as a rather chaotic, zigzag path characterized by collisions with fixed atoms. Each collision results in a change in direction of the electron. Yet because of collisions with atoms in the solid network of the metal conductor, there are two steps backwards for every three steps forward.
>
> [image]

Does this mean that electrical resistance originates from the electrons' collisions with nuclei as well as other electrons, or just with other electrons?

Comment: The answers [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/455217)might be helpful (even if the question is a bit of a mess).

Comment: Short version: the nuclei have a lot more inertia than the other electrons, so they'll cause a much bigger change in the electron's momentum on a collision. But we might rather say that the electron interacts with the phonon states of the crystal lattice than with the individual nuclei.

Answer (score 2):

A conducting electron, in an eigenstate of the periodic potential of a crystalline lattice, will never scatter, assuming the lattice is perfect. This is because its periodic wavefunction already “includes” interaction with the lattice nuclei.

So scattering comes from *distortions* of the lattice. Think of a sudden distortion like an interface that the electron wave could reflect/scatter from. The model you cite is outdated (as of the middle 20th century), although it works reasonably well, as a practical matter, for simple systems.

Lattice distortions come primarily in the form of defects and lattice compression/expansion waves (i.e. phonons). This is why metals tend to have a higher conductivity at lower temperature, because the thermally-excited lattice waves are less populous, so there’s less electron-phonon scattering. This trend continues for lower and lower temperatures until scattering from lattice defects becomes dominant.